# find indices where 2 list differ

Tags: python, list

I have two list. i have to find the indexes where these list differ.

```
case 1: 
a = "node1 ip up ether 40  46 server low".split()
b = "node1 ip <down> ether <number(s)> server <status>".split()
output = [ [[2],[2]], 
           [[4,5],[4]],
           [[7],[6]]  ]

case 2:
a = ' label 0 12000 '.split()
b = ' label  <number>  <number>'.split()
output = [ [[1,2],[1,2]] ]
```

a,b are input list and output is a result list. 
Element in b which differ with a are in enclosed in `<>` for eg. `<blabla>` 
In case 1 and case 2, `output[i][0]` gives indices for `a` and `output[i][1]` gives indices for `b`.

1. In case 1, `up` and `<down>` differ at position `[2,2]`. `40, 46` and `<number(s)>` differ at position `[4,5],[4]` and so on.
2. In case 2, `output[0][0] = [1,2]` corresponds to `0 12000` and `output[0][1] =[1,2]` corresponds to `<number> <number>`.

Comment: in the first case `a` and `b` are not the same length...

Comment: @zenpoy exactly they are not of same length. but few elements are same in both list and in second list elements which differ are shown encapsulated in `<>`.

Comment: 3 -ve votes, atleast give some justification for -ve vote.

Comment: What do you expect to output for a,b,c,d and a,e,f,g,h,I,j,k? How do you decide which group of indices correspond to which index?

Comment: i will try to re-frame question, i have to find sequence of non-matching values in both lists. so for input  `a='a b c d'` and `b='a e f g h I j k'` and output will be `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]`. and for another input `a='a b c d m b c d'` and `b='a e f g h I j k m p q r'` output is `[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]], [[5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11]]]`.

Comment: I'm not sure I got you. see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the requested output for the given two cases.

```
import difflib

def diff_indices(a, b):
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b)
    res = []
    for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in sm.get_opcodes():
        if tag == 'replace':
            res.append([range(i1,i2), range(j1,j2)])
    return res

print diff_indices(
    a="node1 ip up ether 40  46 server low".split(),
    b="node1 ip <down> ether <number(s)> server <status>".split())
#[[[2], [2]], [[4, 5], [4]], [[7], [6]]]
print diff_indices(
    a=' label 0 12000 '.split(),
    b=' label  <number>  <number>'.split())
#[[[1, 2], [1, 2]]]
```

It is not clear what you expect in e.g. this case:

```
a = "node1 ip up ether 40  46 server low".split()
b = "node1 ip <down> ether server <status>".split()
```

Comment: `b = "node1 ip <down> ether server <status>".split() ` is not a valid input for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[k for k, v in enumerate(zip(a,b)) if not v[0] == v[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work.

```
lista="abcd"
listb="accd"
print [ i for i in xrange(min(len(lista),len(listb))) if lista[i] != listb[i] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "node1 ip up ether 40  46 server low".split()
b = "node1 ip <down> ether <number(s)> server <status>".split()

if len(a) > len(b):
    b,a = a,b

a_it = iter(a)
b_it = iter(b)

diffs = []
a_diff = []
b_diff = []

i = 0
start = 0
while i < len(a):
    j = i
    while j < len(b):
        if a[i] == b[j]:
            if a_diff:
                b_diff = range(start,j)
                diffs.append([a_diff,b_diff])
                a_diff = []
                b_diff = []
            i = i + 1
            start = j + 1
        j = j + 1
    a_diff.append(i)
    i = i + 1


if a_diff:
    b_diff = range(start,j)
    diffs.append([a_diff,b_diff])

print diffs
```